# Using enums with the same value for different outcomes? C++

Tags: c++, enums

quick question (also still noob so probably easy answer too..)
Anywho, I'm working on a battleship game and I have enums that display the board, and whether its a hit or miss etc..

```
 enum class EnemyPiece : char{
    SHIP = '?', // when read this comes out as EMPTY
    HIT = 'X',
    MISS = ' ',
    EMPTY = '?'
 }
```

The purpose is that when displaying the board, I want it to show the enum of the board, but I dont want the player to know where the SHIPS are, so I want them to mask as empty.

Sort of like, the board knows there a ship there, but displays as EMPTY, until the player guesses correctly.

EDIT:: sorry, the question is, how to make the enum show EMPTY, but when checked the enum is actually SHIP

Comment: As they have the same value, there are indistinguishable one from the other. I mean you have `EnemyPiece::SHIP == EnemyPiece::EMPTY`.

Comment: Not sure what the question is being asked here

Comment: These values in question are the same, so they cannot be distinguished.

Comment: I have never seen an enum used this way. Separate the visualization from the value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your display function like

```
enum class EnemyPiece : char{ SHIP, HIT, MISS, EMPTY };

char getCharForDisplay(EnemyPiece e)
{
    switch (e) {
        case EnemyPiece::SHIP:  return '?';
        case EnemyPiece::EMPTY: return '?';
        case EnemyPiece::HIT:   return 'X';
        case EnemyPiece::MISS:  return ' ';

    }
}
```